# Results reduced when adding fourth table join

Tags: mysql, database, join

edit: Now for some reason each productid is only showing up once instead of depending on how many variations it has? Any ideas?  (The query I am using is the last query I have listed)

Here is my three table join query

```
SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xco.optionid, xco.option_name
FROM xcart_products xp
JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xp.productid = xc.productid and xc.class = 'Color'
JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xc.classid = xco.classid
ORDER by xp.product DESC
```

Now everything here works great, I get about 2,000 results, everything is organized and arranged correctly.

Now I would like to add a fourth table to run a count of the number of xi.optionid per xi.id, but for some reason I am only getting about 200 results and can't figure out why.  Here is the query I am attempting to run

```
SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, count(xi.optionid) as cnt
    FROM xcart_products xp 
    INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xp.productid = xc.productid AND xc.class = 'Color'
    INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xc.classid = xco.classid 
    INNER JOIN xcart_images_D xi ON xi.optionid = xco.optionid
    GROUP BY xp.product
    ORDER by xp.product DESC
```

Here's the basic schema for each of the tables

```
xcart_products -
    + productid*
    + product
xcart_classes - 
    + classid*
    + productid (xcart_products.productid)
xcart_class_options -
    + optionid*
    + classid (xcart_classes.classid)
    + option_name
xcart_images_D - 
    + imageid*
    + optionid (xcart_class_options.optionid)
    + id (xcart_products.productid)
```

Query I'm currently using -

```
SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, count(xi.optionid) as cnt
FROM xcart_products xp
JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xp.productid = xc.productid AND xc.class = 'Color'
JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xc.classid = xco.classid
LEFT JOIN xcart_images_D xi ON xi.optionid = xco.optionid
GROUP BY xp.product 
ORDER by xp.product DESC
```

Comment: what is the count of records in the images table

Comment: in the first query, you don't have a GROUP BY statement. And also, you're using different kinds of JOINs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) instead.

```
select xp.productid,
    xp.product,
    xc.classid,
    xco.optionid,
    xco.option_name,
    count(xi.optionid) as cnt
from xcart_products xp
inner join xcart_classes xc on xp.productid = xc.productid
    and xc.class = 'Color'
inner join xcart_class_options xco on xc.classid = xco.classid
left outer join xcart_images_D xi on xi.optionid = xco.optionid
group by xp.product
order by xp.product desc
```

Comment: For some reason each productid is only showing up once instead of depending on how many variations it has?  Any ideas?

Comment: You are grouping by xp.product. If one product has mabny productids and you want to see them all, then `group by xp.product, xp.productid`.

Answer (score 1):

User a Left join on the last table.